# PHP time function ($today) for GMT +1

Tags: php, date-time

I tried a lot - But the code at the bottom is always 1 hour behind the local time. It might be a problem of the server-time. But I want to use it for a german website - So I have to set the time to GMT +1.

It would be great if someone could help me...

```
    <?php 
$today = date('N');
if( $today == 1) { ?>
<article class="intro"><div class="content" style="width:auto;float:left;"><h4><?php dynamic_sidebar( 'countdown' ); ?></h4></div></article>
<?php } elseif( $today == 2 ) { ?>
<article class="intro"><div class="content" style="width:290px;"><h4><?php dynamic_sidebar( 'seitenleiste' ); ?></h4></div></article>
<?php } elseif( $today == 3 ) { ?>
<article class="intro"><div class="content" style="width:290px;"><h4><?php dynamic_sidebar( 'seitenleiste' ); ?></h4></div></article>
<?php } elseif( $today == 4 ) { ?>
<article class="intro"><div class="content" style="width:290px;"><h4><?php dynamic_sidebar( 'seitenleiste' ); ?></h4></div></article>
<?php } elseif( $today == 5 ) { ?>
<article class="intro"><div class="content" style="width:290px;"><h4><?php dynamic_sidebar( 'seitenleiste' ); ?></h4></div></article>
<?php } elseif( $today == 6 ) { ?>
<article class="intro"><div class="content" style="width:290px;"><h4><?php dynamic_sidebar( 'seitenleiste' ); ?></h4></div></article>
<?php } elseif( $today == 7 ) { ?>
<article class="intro"><div class="content" style="width:290px;"><h4><?php dynamic_sidebar( 'seitenleiste' ); ?></h4></div></article>
<?php } ?>
```

Thank you so much!

Philipp

Answer (score 1):

Time is one of the things in environment WordPress normalizes to GMT, so all native PHP function give that in WordPress context.

To get time in timezone, set in WordPress settings, try [`date_i18n()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n) instead.

Comment: So do you mean something like that:
<?php 
$today = date_i18n('N');
if( $today == 1) { ?>

Thank you so much!

Comment: @Philipp yes, it should work just as `date()` but using timezone and locale from WP settings.